# Regex for sales prices

Tags: c#, regex, devexpress

I would like to show prices in the following formats.

- 100
- 100,20
- 1.000,20
- 11.000,20
- 111.000,20
- 1.111.000,20

I have made this regex expression, `\d+(\,\d+)?` but it only outputs these numbers:

- 100
- 100,20
- 1000,20
- 11000,20
- 1111000,20

What I'm missing is the thousand-separator. How can I add this?

I have already read these articles, but still no luck.
[MSDN: Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1501)
[DevExpress: Mask Type: Extended Regular Expressions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1501)

Comment: Try `\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?`

Comment: Or `\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?` if you expect exactly two decimal digits

Comment: Well, if you plan to match a decimal separator defined in the system settings, use `\R.`: `\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\R.\d+)?` Unfortunately, I cannot see any digit grouping symbol pattern in the reference you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(\R.\d+)?
```

Here,

- `\d{1,3}` - matches 1 to 3 digits
- `(\.\d{3})*` - matches 0 or more sequences of a literal `.` followed with exactly 3 digits
- `(\R.\d+)?` - matches an optional (1 or 0) sequences of:

  - `\R.` - a decimal separator specified by the System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator property of the current culture
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits

Unfortunately, there is no digit grouping symbol pattern in DevExpress validation regex, so you might want to hard-code the decimal separator the same way as the "thousand separator" (i.e. `\R.` -> `,`).

Comment: Thank you, that did the job!